# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to write to TextWriter/StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-io

I got this weird exception when calling `Write` on a `TextWriter` instance:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.WriteLine(String value)
   at Iot.Device.Common.SimpleFileLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter) in C:\Projects\iot\src\devices\Common\Iot\Device\Common\SimpleFileLogger.cs:line 49
// More irrelevant stuff here...
```

The line in question just does (The writer is certainly not disposed nor closed):

```cs
// _writer is an instance of StreamWriter
_writer.WriteLine($"{time.ToShortDateString()} {time.ToLongTimeString()} - {_category} - {logLevel} - {msg}");
```

According to the docs, `TextWriter.WriteLine` never throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException, and even looking at the sourcecode of that `FlushWriteBuffer` method shows nothing that could cause this (I'm using .NET 5.0):

```cs
private void FlushWriteBuffer(bool calledFromFinalizer = false)
        {
            if (_writePos == 0) return;
            Debug.Assert(_readPos == 0 && _readLength == 0, "FileStream: Read buffer must be empty in FlushWrite!");

            if (_useAsyncIO)
            {
                // Irrelevant case
            }
            else
            {
                WriteCore(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(GetBuffer(), 0, _writePos));
            }

            _writePos = 0;
        }
```

Why do I get this exception? And where is it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `StreamWriter` is *not* thread safe. I was using the above logging task to log from different threads into the same file.

To fix this, create the `StreamWriter` with a synchronized wrapper around it:

```
_writer = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8));
```